Flink acknowledgement ids have expired
There are 2 problems. When I'm using the default header size, 10240 bytes, after some time, the execution raises the following exception:
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$HeaderListSizeException: Header size exceeded max allowed size (10240)

and the application crashes.
Then I've followed the solution in this thread: Getting http2 exception on a Flink Job with a GCP PubSub source but it only fixes if I set the header to something bigger than 3 or 4 MB.
Doing so, I start facing a:
org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were invalid. This could be because the acknowledgement ids have expired or the acknowledgement ids were malformed.

This started happening after we enable the exactly_once_delivery in the PubSub subscription.
Sometimes, the application runs fine for around 2 hours before it crash.
The PubSub subscription's ack deadline is set to 60s.
Flink's checkpoint interval is set to 30s now (but I already tried smaller and bigger intervals).
I have 10 of parallelism and the backpressure is around 2%.
I'm using PubSubSource to connect PubSub and it sinks the info to HDFS.
Flink version is 1.17.2 and Java 8.
Can anybody help me to address this?
